# Android ANR when user is coming from background

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

When the user is comming from background to my app then the app is freezed.
The following logs don't tell me nothing about the issue, but I can't get nothing else.

After a while ANR shows up.
Additional info: I'm using smack to connect to xmpp server.

```
05-19 12:51:53.733 23626-4094/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
05-19 12:51:53.733 23626-4086/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 11(0x39322e35342e32),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
05-19 12:51:53.743 23626-4086/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
05-19 12:51:55.956 23626-4094/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 11(0x39322e35342e32),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
05-19 12:51:55.966 23626-4094/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
05-19 12:51:55.966 23626-4086/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 11(0x39322e35342e32),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
05-19 12:51:55.976 23626-4086/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
05-19 12:51:56.296 23626-23641/com.es.ric I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 64498(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 158(2MB) LOS objects, 23% free, 24MB/31MB, paused 7.233ms total 72.058ms
05-19 12:51:58.308 23626-4094/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 11(0x39322e35342e32),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
05-19 12:51:58.308 23626-4094/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
05-19 12:51:58.318 23626-4086/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 11(0x39322e35342e32),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
05-19 12:51:58.318 23626-4086/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
05-19 12:52:00.531 23626-4094/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 11(0x39322e35342e32),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
05-19 12:52:00.531 23626-4094/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
05-19 12:52:00.531 23626-4086/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 11(0x39322e35342e32),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
05-19 12:52:00.531 23626-4086/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
05-19 12:52:02.733 23626-4094/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 11(0x39322e35342e32),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
05-19 12:52:02.743 23626-4094/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
05-19 12:52:02.763 23626-4086/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 11(0x39322e35342e32),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
05-19 12:52:02.763 23626-4086/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
05-19 12:52:05.005 23626-4094/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 11(0x39322e35342e32),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
05-19 12:52:05.005 23626-4094/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
05-19 12:52:05.005 23626-4086/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 11(0x39322e35342e32),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
05-19 12:52:05.015 23626-4086/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
05-19 12:52:06.247 23626-23636/com.es.ric W/art: Suspending all threads took: 14.191ms
05-19 12:52:07.228 23626-4094/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 11(0x39322e35342e32),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
05-19 12:52:07.228 23626-4094/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
05-19 12:52:07.228 23626-4086/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 11(0x39322e35342e32),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
05-19 12:52:07.228 23626-4086/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
05-19 12:52:09.460 23626-4094/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 11(0x39322e35342e32),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
05-19 12:52:09.460 23626-4094/com.es.ric D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
```

And this is the traces.txt file
https://gist.github.com/rchampa/7c085e8f04bef2bc40ee83501d641344

Comment: extract traces.txt file to check where anr problem come, you can use this command to copy traces.txt  from internal storage to external storage and then pull this adb file,      adb shell "cp /data/anr/traces.txt /storage/extSdCard/"

Comment: @yasiriqbal776 I have already tried but fails because is read only, but I get it with "cp: ./traces.txt: Read-only file system"

Comment: here your trace file data is showing data   at com.spamina.parlamobile.activities.MainActivity$2.onBecameBackground(MainActivity.java:117)
  at com.spamina.parlamobile.utils.Foreground$1.run(Foreground.java:164)    here ANR is problem. have you check this line??

Comment: @yasiriqbal776 yes, I almost solve this issue. Thanks for help!